# CheckBox Declaration in Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, datatable

What is the code needed to show a checkbox in a column of a declared datatable?

In C#:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("DeleteFlag");
```

In ASP:

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="MyCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("DeleteFlag") %>'
                Enabled="False" />
```

Error:

Specified cast is not valid.

Troubleshooting tips:

When casting from a number, the value must be a number less than infinity

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? Bind a checkbox from grid?

Comment: Yes. Or any way to successfully declare a checkbox.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445178/set-checkbox-in-gridview-based-on-datatable-value?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
dt.Columns.Add("DeleteFlag", typeof(bool));
```

give the correct column data type as above